# pagination create bad URL, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, pagination

my pagination creat url like:

```
http://localhost:8000/cars?paginate=5&page=2
```

where this should be:

```
http://localhost:8000/cars/?paginate=5&page=2
```

My view with pagination:

```
{!! $dataset->appends(\Input::except("page"))->render() !!}
```

and this lost `/` where this is needed.
What do I bad ?

Comment: You are using apache as webserver? It has the trailing slashes redirect rule? RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301].

Comment: Yes, I use Apache 2.4.17 and this rule is in .htaccess.

Comment: Why don't you try to use datatables for that. It is having pagination, searching and all you want in tabular format. You can use this package - **laravel-datatables** at https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables